# Office / Excel 365 - Reverting New Save As Popup To Old Design

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I've noticed that my Excel 365 recently got an update so that when I try to save a new file, I get the following pop-up:

[image]

This is a more modern looking design than the legacy "Save as" pop-up, but I prefer the old design since it only required two tabs to get to the "Save" button.

How do I revert back to the old design?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is a more modern looking design than the legacy "Save as" pop-up,
>   but I prefer the old design since it only required two tabs to get to
>   the "Save" button.
>
> How do I revert back to the old design?

For whatever reason, in general any Office UI, which refers to One Drive within Office is known as "backstage".

In order to globally disable this functionality, you must disable, the "Don’t show the backstage when opening or saving files" option within the **File > Options > Save** menu within the applicable Office application.

[image]

> The setting applies to all your Office programs. If you want to use
>   the Save As dialog box without making a setting across Office
>   programs, just press F12 instead of Ctrl+S when you save a file.

Source:

- [Use Save As on the File menu](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-save-as-on-the-file-menu-cf7536a3-6842-4056-b9cc-443a7f44b104)
- [Restore old ‘Save as’ dialog for Office 365 apps on Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/restore-old-save-as-dialog-box)

Comment: This worked for Excel, but Word is still showing the "backstage" variant when exiting even though the above checkbox is checked.  Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: @LloydBanks - The option is supposed to be global, across all Office applications, per the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @LloydBanks - Installed Word 1910 just to verify this behavior.  By default, the new save dialog was enabled.  I enable the option I specified, attempted to save, and got old save dialog style.  Opened Excel 1910 and it was the same save dialog.  **Disable the specified option and the behavior reverted to the new save dialog.** I am using `Word 12130.20344`

Comment: @LloydBanks there is no mention that you need it to work for more then Excel in your question

Comment: @Manuel - Question is more than 4 years old. If the method no longer works that is the reason.